# Stacked using statements vs seperate using statements

Tags: c#, performance, using-statement

While refactoring code I stumbled upon some stacked using statements (I'm talking about 10 to 15-ish).

```
using(X x=new X())
using(Y y=new Y())
using(Z z=new Z())
using(...)
{
    List<X> listX= x.GetParameterListByID(pID);
    List<Y> listY=y.GetParameterListByID(pID);
    ...
    ...
    //other (business) calls/code, like 20-30 lines, that don't need the using instances
}
```

Class example would be something like

```
public class X : IDisposable{
  public List<XParameterInfo> GetParameterListByID(int? pID){
      const string query="SELECT name,value FROM parameters WHERE id=@ID";
      //query code here
      return queryResult;
  }
}
```

And the first thing I thought of was, knowing that a `using` is basicly a `try{} finally{ x.Dispose(); }`, that the using connections would be kept open/active untill the code within the using block is finished while it is only needed to fill one list.

The above is what I assume, correct me if I'm wrong.
Considering what I said is correct, would it be better (performance, but mostly good practice-wise) to write something like

```
List<X> listX;
List<Y> listY;
List<Z> listZ;
...
//for the example here I wrote out 3 but let's talk 10 or more

using(X x=new X())
{ 
   listX=x.GetParameterListByID(pID);
}
using(Y y=new Y())
{ 
   listY=y.GetParameterListByID(pID);
}
using(Z z=new Z())
{ 
   listZ=z.GetParameterListByID(pID);
} 
...
// other calls but now outside the using statements
```

or is it negligible, other than the fact that stacked `using` statements take away the nested code look?

Comment: _"would it be better (performance wise)"_ depends on the types that are used in the `using`s

Comment: Furthermore "what is faster" can easily be tried out yourself, couldnt´it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would it be better (performance wise)

that depends on the types that are used in the using. You can't make a general statement.

Performance is not the only factor, open resources can block other processes or cause memory issues. But on the other side readability is increased with the more compact  first version. So you have to decide if there is an issue at all. If not, why bother? Then chose the best readable and maintainable code.

But you could refactor your code, use a method to encapsulate the usings:

```
// in class X:
public static List<X> GetParameterListByID(int pID)
{
    using(X x = new X())
    { 
       return x.GetParameterListByID(pID);
    }
} 
// and same in other classes
```

Now the code has no usings:

```
List<X> listX = X.GetParameterListByID(pID); // static method called
List<Y> listY = Y.GetParameterListByID(pID); // static method called
```

Comment: "You can't make a general statement." Wouldn´t that make the question quite opinion-based?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Yes, without more informations you cant say what's better. But he can encapsulate the usings in a method as i have shown above. Then he has the best of both versions, no issues with open resources and readability.

Comment: What I mostly wanted to know was whether the performance/open resources issue(s) outweighs the readability part when using the stacked version. Agreed with moving the using part to the actual class in this case.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more aswell on the "depends on used types" part , in this case I'm talking about business class instances, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: @HaroldHemms: a class could implement `IDisposable` but for no obvious reason(like `System.Data.DataTable` for example). Other classes implement it because they are blocking critical system resources on use. It also depends on the time you use them. One task might need a couple of milliseconds and another takes an hour to complete. That's what i meant with "it depends".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Tim said, many DB drivers use "Connection Pooling" to increase the performance of connections, by reusing old ones. So when `Dispose` is called upon connections, they don't really close (except after certain conditions are met), but they are kept idle for subsequent calls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-pooling

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 1 connection for all the queries?

I think this would be a more elegant solution.

```
void Main()
{
    List<X> listX;
    List<Y> listY;
    List<Z> listZ;
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();
        listX=new X().GetParameterListByID(conn, pID);
        listY=new Y().GetParameterListByID(conn, pID);
        listZ=new Z().GetParameterListByID(conn, pID);
    }
}
```